# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/cart?user=root

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc

Here is my Java code

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Utils {

    public static Connection createAndGetDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/college?user=root");
    }
}
```

Upon calling the above method from the servlet `doPost` method, i am getting the following error.

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/college?user=root
```

While the below code is working very well...

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class CreateRow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/college?user=root");
            System.out.println("Connection established..");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        Statement stmt = null;
    }
}
```

> The `Utils.createAndGetDatabaseConnection()` is being called from servlet `doPost` method

#### Relavent dependency’s in `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.30</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to observe your error report, this report type is obviously that your url path is wrong, and you are using native JDBC, and the version of mysql is 8.0.*, then you can check your Is the driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver, and your code doesn't seem to register the driver class, can I take a look at your driver class?
I don't seem to see your driver class, i.e. you can add this code in your class:

```
static {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```